# glsl imageStore, followed by imageLoad, is it coherent?

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures, compute-shader

I know that using `imageStore` and followed by `imageRead` within a different invocation within the same dispatch needs the coherent keyword to be correctly read.

However, can I read the value *within the same dispatch* without using `coherent`?

Or in other words, when I have this:

```
layout(r8ui) uniform uimage2D input_texture;
void main(){
  ivec2 coords = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);
  imageStore(input_texture, coords, ivec4(128));
  int value = imageLoad(input_texture, coords).r;
}
```

**Is `value` guaranteed to be 128, even without the coherent keyword?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are always able to read values written by your shader instance without the `coherent` qualifier *as long as*:

1. No other instance of the shader writes to that particular location in the image/buffer.
2. You are reading the value back through the *same image/buffer variable* as you wrote it. Two separate image/buffer variables can refer to the same memory address (binding the same image/buffer to different variables). But implementations are not required to cache accesses to the same memory through different variables.

   The `restrict` qualifier can be used on the image variable to make it explicit that this is the case. Indeed, people should use `restrict` by default unless they explicitly intend to access the same memory through multiple objects.